# Xcode: Why can I #import a file from my static library that is a 'Project' header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I have two projects in my workspace. A framework project I'm developing and also a different application. For some reason in my application project I can't include the Public Headers of my framework project, but I can include the only Project Header file.

How I would like to import my framework:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
```

What Xcode will only allow me to compile:

```
#import <MyFramework/SuperSecretClass.h>
```

In my framework I have my Public headers and project headers configured correctly in the 'Copy Headers' section of my Build Phases (public header in public, other 'private' header in project.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are the headers in the correct place in the Framework bundle? Is your header search path set correctly?